# How to change the label of an existing button

Tags: orbeon

I am able to configure the visible buttons for my form with

```
<property as="xs:string"
          name="oxf.fr.detail.buttons.myform.contact"
          value="save-draft send submit"/>
```

Now my question is how can I change the label of a specific button.

I know that it is possible to override properties, but I can't find the original label definitions anywhere. I found this example,  but it isn't working for me:

```
<property as="xs:string"
          name="oxf.fr.resource.*.*.en.detail.buttons.submit"
          value="Fancy Submit"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The property you are using seems correct, but Orbeon Forms needs to be restarted for overridden resources to take effect.

Comment: Thank you for the hint, but restarting the system did not help either.